# ckeditor bidi force use direction rtl or ltr

Tags: ckeditor

i'm using ckeditor 4 and would like to allow my customers to use rtl or ltr directions - but since i'm going to send the output as email message i want to always have the direction attribute to be used.

for some reason, if i'm using the hebrew or arabic version of ckeditor - it simply omit the rtl instead of writing it. is there a way to force ckeditor to write the direction?

i tried this settings:

```
config.language = 'he';          
config.contentsLangDirection = 'ltr';
```

i've looked in the ckeditor documentation but found nothing about forcing direction tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';` or `config.contentsLangDirection = 'ltr';` in your config file.

Or:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'instance-name', {
    contentsLangDirection: 'rtl'
} );
```

You can find documentation [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsLangDirection)

You can also use a [BIDI plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/bidi).

Answer (score 0):

onkeypress for textarea please call this function

```
function checkArabic( character ) {
    var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    return arabic.test(character);
}
```

then if true set dir='rtl' for html iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, and I needed the same functionality so I did the following and it solved the issue, so maybe it will still help someone.

You can do it by checking the dir attribute of the "p" element for example.
If it empty - then its RTL - so force it by writing this code :

```
    CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function ( event ) {
    event.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
        elements: {
            p: function( element ) {
                if(element.attributes.dir=="" || element.attributes.dir==null)
                element.attributes.dir = 'rtl';
            }
        }
    });
} );
```